# Django new WebSocket(url)

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am trying to do a chat app in django with channels. I try to do it from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cw8-KFVXpTE). But when I run it I get in console `(index):16 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1//8000/ws/socket-server/' failed:` . The moment in video is 8:31 and the program is working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, see how do I ask a good question [ask] and also see [what topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.